# Primefaces' expanding datatables sharing the same pagination state?

Tags: jsp, primefaces

Primefaces' expanding datatables sharing the same pagination state ?
I am working on primefaces7. I have a primefaces datatable whose row would be expand to load subtable data, but I find the subtales are sharing the same pagination state.

The steps are as following:

> 1. In the code, set all the number of rows on each page of sub table to be 3, then start the application.
> 2. Click the first row of the main table to load the data of the first sub table, the data is load with 3 rows on each page.
> 3. Change the number of rows of the first sub table from 3 to 6, the first sub table will load the data with 6 rows on each page.
> 4. Click the second row on the main table, the second sub table was still load with 6 rows on each page, however, the right behavior should be 3 rows on each page.
> 5. Change the number of rows on the second sub table from 6 to 3.
> 6. Collapse the first row on the main table, and expand it again, now the first subtable is load with 3 rows on each page, which is different form the expect result that it should load data with 6 rows on each page.

The following two iamge is provided to give more clear information.
https://note.youdao.com/yws/public/resource/944651b2b0a5f1fd15ba638f29761212/xmlnote/BF343E65325749A1A1AC1A4CC2BA4176/3832

https://note.youdao.com/yws/public/resource/944651b2b0a5f1fd15ba638f29761212/xmlnote/1D7E179E340442B48EC813DF2BBAF63A/3834

Here is the code.

```
<p:dataTable var="hosp"
                 binding = "#{hospitalController.hospitalTable}"
                 value="#{hospitalController.hospData}"
                 paginator="true"
                 rows="10"
                 paginatorPosition="bottom"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} of {totalPages} pages, {totalRecords} records"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 lazy="true"
                 id="hospitalTable"
                 widgetVar="hospitalTable"
                 >
        <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{hospitalController.doToggle(hosp.hospitalId)}"/>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Hospital List" />

        </f:facet>

        <p:column style="width:16px">
             <p:rowToggler></p:rowToggler>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Hospital Code">
            <h:outputText value="#{hosp.hospitalId}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Hospital Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{hosp.hospitalName}" />
        </p:column>


        <p:rowExpansion>
                <p:panelGrid columnClasses="label, value">
                    <p:dataTable value="#{hospitalController.subHospData}"
                                 var="subHosp"
                                 id="subHospTable"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 rows="3"
                                 lazy="true"
                                 paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                                 currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} of {totalPages} pages, {totalRecords} records"
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="3, 6"
                                 >

                        <p:column headerText="Hospital Name" filterBy="#{subHosp.hospitalName}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{subHosp.hospitalName}"  />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Hospital Area">
                            <h:outputText value="#{subHosp.areaName}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Contact Person">
                            <h:outputText value="#{subHosp.contactPerson}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panelGrid>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
```

It seems all the sub tables are sharing the same pagination state, how to separate them to let each sub table keep its own pagination state?

Comment: All subtables indeed are sharing the same `value="#{hospitalController.subHospData}"`

Comment: Hi Selaron, at this line: <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{hospitalController.doToggle(hosp.hospitalId)}"/>  while the row expanding, I post the hospitalId to server, then the subtables can load different subHospData

Comment: Hmm but I fear the entire outer dataTable is re-rendered on each row-toggle, isn't it?

Comment: I do not know how to verify whether the outer datatable is re-rendered.? Any suggestions? On the server log, only sub datatable data is loaded while expnding the out datatable's row.

Comment: Using the browser dev tools you can inspect the answer. It states which component is updated. In the primefaces showcase this is the entire table when expanding a row, but I'm not sure if this is the cause for your issue, was just a hint. Best thing to do would include adding a real [mcve] to enable others reproduce your problem easily.